# Верстка блока "навыки"

Tags: html, css

Есть однотипные блоки с названиями. 
Верно ли верстать через псеводоэлементы before? или есть более лучший способ (с точки зрения качества, производительности)?

```css
.skills__name--is.active:before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/inY4HR/check.png") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.skills__name:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="skills__name--is active">html5</span>
<span class="skills__name--is active">item2</span>
<span class="skills__name--is active">item3</span>
<span class="skills__name--is active">item3</span>
<span class="skills__name">item4</span>
<span class="skills__name">item5</span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Если это не настоящие чекбоксы, а имитация, то сойдёт и так. Также, на мой взгляд, можно обойтись без картинки.

```css
.skills__name.active:before {
  content: '\2713';
  line-height: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #0093d7;
}

.skills__name:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="skills__name active">html5</span>
<span class="skills__name active">item2</span>
<span class="skills__name active">item3</span>
<span class="skills__name active">item3</span>
<span class="skills__name">item4</span>
<span class="skills__name">item5</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Или вот пример с настоящими чекбоксами:

```css
label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.checkbox__item {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkbox input:checked+.checkbox__item {
  background-color: #0093d7;
}

.checkbox input:checked+.checkbox__item:before {
  content: '\2713'
}
```

```html
<label>
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <span class="checkbox__item"></span>
  </span>
  <span>CSS3</span>
</label>
<label>
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
 <span class="checkbox__item"></span>
  </span>
  <span>БЭМ</span>
</label>
<label>
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkbox__item"></span>
  </span>
  <span>Item3</span>
</label>
<label>
  <span class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="checkbox__item"></span>
  </span>
  <span>Item4</span>
</label>
```